# Query XML document in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-openxml

I am looking for a SQL Server query that will allow me to retrieve the ReferencesValues in a tabular result with a ParentKey field that refers to the 'key' field in the tag '* Reference'.

xml :

```
<ReferenceType>
      <Reference>
        <Key>100000000517</Key>
        <Code>AGDS</Code>
        <Label>Member GDS / OVS</Label>
      </Reference>
      <ReferencesValues>
        <Key>200000003678</Key>
        <Code>FNGDSB</Code>
        <Label>ad1</Label>
      </ReferencesValues>
      <ReferencesValues>
        <Key>200000000221</Key>
        <Code>GDS01</Code>
        <Label>ad54</Label>
      </ReferencesValues>
    </ReferenceType>
```

Example result:

```
    Key          Code    Label           ParentKey
    200000003678 FNGDSB   ad1            100000000517
    200000000221 GDS01   ad54            100000000517
```

Comment: What about the wealth of resources out there on querying XML in SQL Server didn't you understand? What about your attempt didn't work? What *was* your attempt? You're tagged [[tag:openxml]] too; why do you want to use that ancient method when SQL Server has supported XQuery since 2005?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only tricky thing is to get the reference parent value:

```sql
DECLARE @x xml = N'<ReferenceType>
      <Reference>
        <Key>100000000517</Key>
        <Code>AGDS</Code>
        <Label>Member GDS / OVS</Label>
      </Reference>
      <ReferencesValues>
        <Key>200000003678</Key>
        <Code>FNGDSB</Code>
        <Label>ad1</Label>
      </ReferencesValues>
      <ReferencesValues>
        <Key>200000000221</Key>
        <Code>GDS01</Code>
        <Label>ad54</Label>
      </ReferencesValues>
    </ReferenceType>'

    SELECT  n.value('Key[1]', 'bigint') [key]
    ,       n.value('Code[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') code
    ,       n.value('Label[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') label
    ,       n.value('../Reference[1]/Key[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS parentkey
    FROM    @x.nodes('ReferenceType/ReferencesValues') t(n)
```

There are some optimizations one can do as well:

```
    SELECT  n.value('(Key/text())[1]', 'bigint') [key]
    ,       n.value('(Code/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') code
    ,       n.value('(Label/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') label
    ,       n.value('(../Reference[1]/Key/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS parentkey
    FROM    @x.nodes('ReferenceType/ReferencesValues') t(n)
```

or traversing xml in two steps to avoid looking behind:

```sql
    SELECT  n.value('(Key/text())[1]', 'bigint') [key]
    ,       n.value('(Code/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') code
    ,       n.value('(Label/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') label
    ,       t.value('(Reference[1]/Key/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS parentkey
    FROM    @x.nodes('ReferenceType') t(t)
    cross apply t.nodes('ReferencesValues') n(n)
```

Comment: @ Siggemannen :Thank you very much for your help, your technique works great, and it has saved me a lot of time

Comment: Glad to hear! You can approve the answer also if it was helpful =)